# Semantic UI React dropdown does not set the value onChange: React+ Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I am implementing a semantic-ui-react dropdown and I am unable to set the value of this dropdown on change event.

Help would be appreciated

```
//options object
const options =  [
  {name: "val1" , label: "val1"},
  {name: "val2" , label: "val2"},
  {name: "val3" , label: "val3"}
]

this.state= {location: ''} //state object


//onchange event
dropdownChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data:any) => {
    this.setState({[data.name]:data.value})
}

//select component
<Select options={options}
  name="location"  
  value={this.state.location}
  onChange={this.dropdownChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: You need to add a `value` key to the array of data.

Look at how they generate data in their example :

```
const countryOptions = _.map(faker.definitions.address.country, country => ({
  key: country,
  text: country,
  value: country
}));
```

OLD ANSWER:
There is no such propertie as `data.name` in the `onChange` handler ([it prints undefined in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semanticuireactexample-0ei16))

I guess you should populate `location` key in the state :

```
dropdownChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data:any) => {
    this.setState({location: data.value})
}
```

Comment: I am using this as a general handler ,  this.setState({[data.name]:data.value}) ; Also I am able to get the info related to this data object, but "value" field is not getting set

Comment: I missed the obvious: you need to add a `value` key in your array of data :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
//onchange event
dropdownChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data:any) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:data.value})
}
```

Comment: Able to get the name property, the problem is only with data.value